# How to import dashboard into Grafana using Ansible?

Tags: json, import, ansible, grafana

Has anyone got any ideas on how to go about this? I want to import a json file for a dashboard into grafana using ansible, preferably without an API is that possible?

I have tried copying it to /var/lib/grafana and have tried to copy it into the dashboard/provision directory but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, unfortunately, does not contain enough information on what you've actually tried to do and what issues did you encounter, so there is no way to suggest a solution on a specific problem, thus only a general answer is possible.

A common way to manage the dashboards with Ansible would be to use [`community.grafana.grafana_dashboard`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/grafana/grafana_dashboard_module.html) or [`grafana.grafana.dashboard`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/grafana/grafana/dashboard_module.html#ansible-collections-grafana-grafana-dashboard-module) modules. Both of them require usage of Grafana API, though.

If you want to configure Grafana via its configuration files, you can try [`grafana.grafana.grafana`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-ansible-collection/tree/main/roles/grafana) role, or even use [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) or [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) modules to [deploy](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#provision-folders-structure-from-filesystem-to-grafana) the provision configuration file to `provisioning/dashboards` and the set of the dashboard files to `/etc/dashboards` from your repository.